# What does this phrase mean: "His set shoulders"?

Tags: adjectives, synonyms

What does the adjective *set* refer to in this case? What would be a synonym for it?

Comment: Can you give a couple of sentences to show the context, please, Anna? I'd expect something like 'Boromir, his shoulders set, forced a path through the snow.'

Comment: It's a description of a football player. "Everyone is staring at us again, staring at Nick and his set shoulders and his plaster-wrapped leg."

Comment: It means 'fixed / held squarely / rigidly' here, but a straight swap wouldn't sound right.

Comment: The medical meaning of _set_ may apply here.  Dislocated joints and fractured bones can be _set_ or put back in anatomic position.

Comment: Yes, but 'shoulders set in plaster' would be used 99+% of the time if they hadn't already been referred to (and we could trust OP to give us all the necessary context here). _Couldn't_ we?

Answer (score 1):

Here is all the context anyone should need to fully appreciate the poster's quotation. The story "A Hundred Summers," by Beatriz Willia, introduces Graham, a dreamy football player, as follows:

> Graham Pendleton pauses with his knife and fork suspended in the air. He fills his chair, fills the entire room: all square shoulders and slick brown hair catching gold from the lights above us. Up close like this, he is absurdly handsome, every angle in perfect symmetry.

A bit later, Nick Greenwald, a friend of Graham's who is also a football player and also dreamy, shows up, eliciting the description that prompted the poster's question:

> He [Nick] must think I’m some brainless boy-crazy girl, one of dozens sighing after him because he’s tall and handsome and plays football. Maybe he’s right. Maybe I’m no different from those boy-crazy girls, enslaved to the mating instinct. What do I know of him, really, other than that he’s tall and handsome and plays football, that he has unyielding eyes and moves like a leopard?
>
> Graham calls for a menu, and Nick studies it briefly, while the waiter stands just behind his shoulder. Everyone is staring at us again, staring at Nick and **his set shoulders** and his plaster-wrapped leg.

Nick moves like a leopard with a plaster-wrapped leg because he fractured his fibula—presumably in a rowdier-than-usual afternoon pursuit of a Thomson's gazelle. In any event, his shoulders, like Graham's, are not set in a body cast but are squared, muscular, and taut with kinetic possibility.

In short, the explanation Edwin Ashworth gives in his second comment above is exactly correct:

> It means 'fixed / held squarely / rigidly' here, but a straight swap wouldn't sound right.